# HttpUrlConnection Get method returns status code 405

Tags: java, get, httpurlconnection

I am trying to fetch data from the server using `HttpURLConnection`. The request is a `GET` request. But, it always returns status code `405(BAD_METHOD)`. Below is the method I wrote:

```
URL url2 = new URL("http://www.example.com/api/client_list?");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url2
                .openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setReadTimeout(NET_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", clientRole));

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
connection.connect();
```

**getQuery()**

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

While if perform the same using `HttpClient`, I get the desired output. Below is the same operation with `HttpClient`

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/api/client_list?client_id=" + rolename;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong with HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: In the first code snippet what package `getQuery()` belongs to?

Comment: Make sure that you call `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");` before `connection.setDoInput(true);` and 
`connection.setDoOutput(true);`. Otherwise, you're telling HttpURLConnection to do a GET after the connection has been established.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that setDoInput(true) causes the method to be set to POST.

Comment: @PM77-1 posted `getQuery()`. Please check. Its an utility to add parameters to the url.

Comment: I think you need to remove `?` from the url

Comment: @Mzf I did that already. It didn't worked.

Comment: @MikeLaren Corrected that. Now its returning `BAD_REQUEST(400)`

Comment: @Nitish have u tried with InputStream for reading the response?

Comment: BAD_REQUEST(400) means that the server accepted the connection and read the request but was unable to process it, probably due to something being missing. You should check the server logs to find out what was missing, but I suspect that the request string didn't have all the required parameters and that's why the server rejected it. Try using a tool like Wireshark, Fiddler or Charles Proxy to compare the network traffic of each request to see if you can spot the difference. Also check headers such as Content-Type and Content-Disposition.

Comment: @Krishna How does that going to help out?I'll read the stream only when I get status as `HTTP_OK`.

Comment: @Nitish u getting still same error?

Comment: @Nitish Remove this both properties connection.setReadTimeout(NET_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS); then try to run

Comment: @Nitish u need to change like this. URL url2 = new URL("http://www.example.com/api/client_list?Authencation="+urvalue);

Answer (score 15):

`connection.setDoInput(true);` forces POST request. Make it `connection.setDoInput(false);`

Comment: As for JDK 1.8: `connection.setDoInput(true);` **does not force** POST. In fact, it is useless because `true` is the default (according to Javadoc). And the default Http-Method of `HttpURLConnection` seems to be GET. Try with this code: `connection.setDoInput(true);
System.out.print(((HttpURLConnection)connection).getRequestMethod());`

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I ran into with the OP's code is that opening the output stream...:

`OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();`

...implicitly changes the connection from a "GET" (which I initially set on the connection via setProperties) to a "POST", thus giving the 405 error on the end point. If you want to have a flexible httpConnection method, that supports both GET and POST operations, then only open the output stream on non-GET http calls.

Comment: Absolute hero you are, I was banging my head for an hour before I found this.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to me into the `GET` method parameters are to be send as the part of the URL so  try this.

```
String request = "http://example.com/index.php?param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
URL url = new URL(request); 
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setUseCaches (false);



 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

try it.

Comment: setRequestMethod("GET"); ===>>> cannot find symbol

Comment: Which URL Connection you using ? @MrSalesi